# Laravel 5.2 - Send Email Through SparkPost Using Dedicated IP

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I'm working on a project written in Laravel 5.2 that requires me to send email through a dedicated IP address so that we can whitelist the IP address of the sender (in this case, SparkPost) to allow deliverability within a corporate environment with very strict anti-spam rules.

I have setup my SparkPost account with a dedicated IP address and I can send emails, but is sending email via the default IP pool instead of using my dedicated IP address. As a result, the emails are marked as spam.

Here is a reference from SparkPost about how to specify a specific IP pool:
https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/2002977

My question is this: How can I specify to use the dedicated IP when using Laravel's `Mail::send` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mr. Phoenix's response might work if you're using the SMTP protocol to communicate with SparkPost, but my application is using SparkPost's API.

After a little bit of help from Mr.Phoenix (thank you, btw), I was able to trace how the message was being sent and found that that the `createSparkPostDriver` method in the `TransportManager` has a way to configure options based on what you indicate in your `services.php` file in the `config` folder.

In the end, all I had to do was add the following to my `services.php` file:

```
'sparkpost' => [
    'secret' => env('SPARKPOST_SECRET'),
    'options' => [
        "ip_pool" => env('SPARKPOST_IP_POOL_ID'),
    ]
],
```

And then add the variables to my `.env` file:

```
SPARKPOST_SECRET=abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
SPARKPOST_IP_POOL_ID=dedicated_ip_pool
```

Answer (score 1):

in the document it specifies that you have to add an additional header so it can route it through the specific ip

`X-MSYS-API: { "options" : { "ip_pool" : "my_new_ip_pool" } }`

otherwise the default is used.

`Mail::send` doesn't offer any shortcuts for adding additional headers so you have to use the underlying Swift Message. Not quite sure about the value of the header.. Try testing with mail driver set to `log` .

```
    Mail::send("template.blade",$data,function($message){
$message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MSYS-API', '{ "options" : { "ip_pool" : "my_new_ip_pool" } }')
});
```

[Mail::Send Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail)
[SwiftMailer Headers documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/headers.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up going with the API options instead of the SMTP header.